# Program to print the lower value of age in input python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to write a program to get the name and age of person and print the name and age of the youngest person after the name `STOP` has been introduced (without lists)

I have this so far and I have no idea on how to get to the lower value

```
name = "Joao"
ageMin = 0
while name != "STOP":
   name = input("Digite o nome: ")
   age = int(input("Digite a sua idade: "))
   identity = name, ageMin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct/do `2` things more for your `code` to work:

- Compare the entered age against the youngest age so far and do the appropriate things if it is *younger* (less than)
- Start the minimum age off as something like `200` as nobody is going to be younger than `0` so this will never work as it stands

So here it is working just fine:

```
name = "Joao"
ageMin = 200
nameMin = name
while name != "STOP":
   name = input("Digite o nome: ")
   age = int(input("Digite a sua idade: "))
   if age < ageMin:
       ageMin = age
       nameMin = name

print("youngest:", nameMin, "at age", ageMin)
```

Comment: Please `up-vote` too to show your appreciation! Thank you **:)**